# Linking my custom docker container to another custom container

Tags: docker, boot2docker, dockerfile, docker-compose

I have two Rails docker containers:

The first is the the front-end application (container1) and the other is the backend API (container2).

The frontend can be access at http://0.0.0.0:3000. The front-end connects to the backend API via http://0.0.0.0:5000.

I have used this to start the frontend linking it to the backend

```
docker run --name=frontend --publish=3000:3000 --link=postgis:postgres --link=backend:backend --volume=/var/app:/app --tty=false --interactive=false --detach=true frontend
```

Backend is running as usual

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                            NAMES
cd4521524caf        backend             "/bin/bash -l -c /setu"   About an hour ago   Up About an hour    0.0.0.0:5000->5000/tcp                         backend
```

The linked backend I observed has added an entry in the /etc/hosts

```
172.17.0.712    cd4521524caf
127.0.0.1   localhost
::1 localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
172.17.0.2  postgres 12b29087618e postgis
```

How can I get/expose the name and alias of my backend docker container to register properly in /etc/hosts and also how can I expose an environment variable that will have the value of 172.17.0.12:5000.

I noticed other docker containers (like postgis) that I have linked add environment variables but mine (backend) doesn't.

I would like my environment variable to be like

```
BACKEND_API="http://172.17.0.12:5000"
```

And the /etc/hosts entry to be:

```
172.17.0.712    backend cd4521524caf backend
```

Comment: As a side comment, unless you need to access the backend container from places other than the frontend container, you don't need to add `-p 5000:5000` there -- adding `--link` on the frontend container will make sure that the two containers can communicate, and that would further isolate your backend from the outside world.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your software supports name resolution via `/etc/hosts` (which is very, very likely unless you're doing name resolution by hand in the frontend), you could just use `-e BACKEND_API="http://backend:5000"` and it will automatically pull the correct IP from `/etc/hosts` directly.